# Is there a way to avoid repetitive method calls in if else blocks?

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to improve this code to avoid repetitive method calls.Is there a way to fix this??I don't want to call the same methods updateIndicator and createErrorResponse method every time in if else blocks.

```
if (e.getRawStatusCode() == NOT_FOUND) {
    String errorDetails = createNotFoundDetails(transactionId);
    updateIdentifier(identifier);
    return createErrorResponse(MISSING_VALID_TRANSACTION_ID_ERROR_MSG, errorDetails);
}
else if (e.getRawStatusCode() == UNAUTHORIZED) {
    updateIdentifier(identifier);
    if (responseHeaderValue.equals(TOKEN_EXPIRED) ) {
        return createErrorResponse(UNABLE_TO_REACH_SVC_PROVIDER_ERROR_MSG,
                                   INVALID_RESPONSE_FROM_SVC_PROVIDER_EXPIRED_TOKEN_ERROR_DETAILS);
    }
    return createErrorResponse(UNABLE_TO_REACH_SVC_PROVIDER_ERROR_MSG,
                               INVALID_RESPONSE_FROM_SVC_PROVIDER_INVALID_TOKEN_ERROR_DETAILS);
}
else {
    updateIdentifier(identifier);
    return createErrorResponse(UNABLE_TO_REACH_SVC_PROVIDER,
                               UNABLE_TO_REACH_SVC_PROVIDER_ERROR_DETAILS);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: The parameters for the method calls are different, so there is little hope ...

Comment: `else`after `return` makes no sense

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public static method in that class. For example

```
public static errorResponse method(identifier) {
    updateIdentifier(identifier);
    return createErrorResponse(
    UNABLE_TO_REACH_SVC_PROVIDER, UNABLE_TO_REACH_SVC_PROVIDER_ERROR_DETAILS);
}
```

And in your code you would make calls to your method.

Answer (score 0):

First you can extract `updateIdentifier(identifier);` statement out of the if else block as it is executed in each branch.

Then your code will be having if else logic and single call inside each branch to `createErrorResponse(...)` method. This is not a bad code given the different conditions you have to check. Anyway if you need to further reduce, There are different approaches that you can take. Please note that this will reduce the code you have here, but will add more code to somewhere else. Maybe few more classes too.

I have implemented a sample using `Enums` this is for you to get an idea about what you can do.

```
public enum Error
{
    ERROR1TEST
            {
                @Override
                ErrorResponse createErrorResponse()
                {
                    return new ErrorResponse( "First Error" );
                }
            },
    ERROR2TEST2
            {
                @Override
                ErrorResponse createErrorResponse()
                {
                    return new ErrorResponse( "Second Error" );
                }
            },
    ERROR3
            {
                @Override
                ErrorResponse createErrorResponse()
                {
                    return new ErrorResponse( "Third Error" );
                }
            },
    ;

    abstract ErrorResponse createErrorResponse();
}
```

Now based on your `e.getRawStatusCode()` and `responseHeaderValue` we need to create above Enum Constant names. Inside each enum constant we have a method to build the Error response for each scenario.

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        CustomEvent e = new CustomEvent();
        e.setEvent( 1 );
        String headerValue = "TEST";

        ErrorResponse errorResponse = createErrorResponse( e, headerValue );
        System.out.println( errorResponse );
    }

    private static ErrorResponse createErrorResponse( CustomEvent e, String headerValue )
    {
        String name = "ERROR" + e.getRawStatusCode() + headerValue;
        return Error.valueOf( name ).createErrorResponse();
    }
```

Output:  `ErrorResponse{errorMsg='First Error'}`

Using this you can reduce your code to something like

```
updateIdentifier(identifier);
return createErrorResponse(e.getRawStatusCode(),responseHeaderValue );
```

Please note that this is just a demonstration. You might need to adjust accordingly. If undefined states are expected handle the  `No enum constant Error` thrown when `Error.valueOf( name )` is called.
Other classes used

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    String errorMsg;

    public ErrorResponse( String errorMsg )
    {
        this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
    }

    @Override public String toString()
    {
        return "ErrorResponse{" +
                "errorMsg='" + errorMsg + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}


public class CustomEvent
{
    private int event;

    public int getEvent()
    {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent( int event )
    {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public int getRawStatusCode()
    {
        return this.event;
    }
}
```